# Connecting homomorphism of exact sequence of Ext groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $0\to M\to L\to N\to0$ be an exact sequence of modules over a ring $A$. Having an $A$-module $K$ we obtain the exact sequence of Ext groups

$$0\to Hom_A(N,K)\to Hom_A(L,K)\to Hom_A(M,K)\stackrel{\delta}{\to}Ext^1_A(N,K)\to...$$

with some connecting homomorphism $\delta$.

Having $\varphi\in Hom_A(M,K)$, how to define $\delta(\varphi)$?

Answer (score 4):

An “explicit” description of $\delta(\varphi)$ can be obtained via a push-out: consider the push-out diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> M @>>> L @>>> N @>>> 0 \\
@. @V{\varphi}VV @VVV @| @. \\
0 @>>> K @>>> K' @>>> N @>>> 0
\end{CD}
$$
Then the (equivalence class of) the exact sequence $0\to K\to K'\to N\to0$, as an element in $\operatorname{Ext}_A^1(N,K)$ is precisely $\delta(\varphi)$. I believe that all books in homological algebra contain this description; the connection between homomorphisms and extensions is very well explained in Hilton-Stammbach.

Answer (score 3):

Let $E$ denote the original short exact sequence $0 \rightarrow M \rightarrow L \rightarrow N \rightarrow 0$. Let $\phi \in Hom(M,K)$, then $\delta( \phi)=Ext^1(N, \phi )(E)$ (note that $Ext^1(N,-)$ is a functor and so $Ext^1(N, \phi )$ is a homomorphism $Ext^1(N,M) \rightarrow Ext^1(N,K)$). This is Theorem 3.2 in the Homology book of Maclane.